# Reading web.config value through javascript

Tags: javascript

I have web.config with the given value:

```
<appSettings>
        <add key="vDirectory" value="fr" />
        <add key="BookingSummaryPage" value="/pli/forms/BookingSummary.aspx" />
</appSettings>
```

Now I want to read the value of "vDirectory" through java script.

I am using below code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function test()
{
var t='<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("vDirectory").ToString() %>'
alert(t);
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="test();" />
```

The error generated is:

```
Error 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings' is a 'property' but is used like a 'method'
```

Comment: That should work (although is not the most recomended way to handle this). What does the alert show? an empty value?

Comment: Its displaying error Error 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings' is a 'property' but is used like a 'method'

Comment: I deleted my answer Manoj because it isn't what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: this doesn't answer your first issue, but still applies after you fix that.  If vDirectory was something like "c:\new folder" you'd end up with a newline in `t`.

I'm not sure what language you're using but you want to run the string though addslashes() (or the equivalent in your language) before you print it out like that:

```
var t='<%=addslashes(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("vDirectory").ToString()) %>';
```

Or even better, JSON encode it if there's a function for that:

```
// Note no quotes as json_encode will add them
var t=<%=json_encode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("vDirectory").ToString()) %>;
```

Comment: It is giving error Error The name 'json_encode' does not exist in the current context

Comment: any idea how I can add "addslashes" in javascript?

Comment: You need to do the addslashes bit in your server-side code not javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vDirectory"].ToString()

Please note that square brackets are used instead of normal brackets.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a property (variable), you can't *call* it, like its a method (function).  So don't you need:

```
<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetKey("vDirectory")%>
```

...?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx